# QGIS Server does not publish Oracle Spatial Layer

Tags: qgis, server

I want to publish a Oracle Spatial Layer which is defined in a QGIS Project with the QGIS Server as a WMS.
The capabilities document of the QGIS Server does not include the layer description of the Oracle Spatial Layer. If i try this for example with a PostGis Layer it will work. Is there a solution about this.

My Version of QGIS is 2.4 for Windows 64 bit and i installed the QGIS Server over the OSGEO setup on the same system.